# reshaping dataframe using pivot/groupby by id and date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I want to reshaping my dataframe so that I have all the values that have the same `encouterid` and `Chartime` on the same line even if the `interventionId` is different :

[image]

What I have for this output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql(query, con)) 
df = df.groupby(['encounterId','chartTime','interventionId','verboseForm'])['terseForm'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series) 
df = df.dropna(axis='columns') 
fichier = df.to_csv("resultat.csv", sep='|')
print(df)
```

Sample of the dataframe :

`encounterId chartTime           interventionId verboseForm

323         2013-06-01 00:00:00 9899           Dort                                Dort
                                11870          100 %                                100
            2013-06-01 01:00:00 11870          99 %                                 99
            2013-06-01 02:00:00 11870          100 %                               100
324         2013-06-01 00:00:00 9899           Dort                                Dort
                                11870          98 %                                98
            2013-06-01 01:00:00 11870          99 %                                 99
            2013-06-01 02:00:00 11870          99 %                               99`

Solution should be :

`encounterId chartTime           verboseForm  verboseForm  verboseForm  verboseForm  ...
323         2013-06-01 00:00:00 Dort         100          sibli.exp++   Dort   ...

324         2013-06-01 01:00:00 =100 %       100          Came          Calme  ...
            2013-06-01 01:00:00 =99 %        98           Dort          Calme  ...
            2013-06-01 02:00:00 100 %        100          sibli         Dort    ...`
 
I have been unable to get the desired shape.

Comment: try: `df = df.set_index(['encounterId','chartTime',''interventionId])`

Comment: didn't work  
`325         2013-06-01 00:00:00 11870          96 %                          92497
                                                    9899           Dort                          11885
                                                    4835           Bonne entrée air       67193`

Comment: can you please format the table, it is super hard to understand right now, if possible, best would be if you can provide the code to generate your data frame, first few rows would suffice.

Comment: @YOLO the data comes from a SQL server database to which I'm connecting too with python driver, the lines are above with the columns: encounterId, chartTime, interventionId, verboseForm